# Summing a column of expressions in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, expression, sum

The detail row in my table contains a column with an expression:

```
=sum(Fields!one.Value) / sum(Fields!two.Value)
```

I want to sum that column, but the results I get are not the sum of the ratios, but the ratio of the sums.

**For example:**

```
     sum(Fields!one.Value)  sum(Fields!two.Value)    ratio
              3                      6                0.5 
              3                      6                0.5 
total:        6                     12                0.5
```

I want the **bottom right corner** value to be the **sum of the values** above it (i.e. `1.0`), not the ratio of the values to the left of it. I've tried calculating the sum as:

```
sum( sum(Fields!one.Value) / sum(Fields!two.Value) )
```

but that gives the **`0.5`**.

Anyone have any ideas?

---

**My Solution:**

I added another column to the right of the ratio column and set its visibility to "not visible". In the detail row, I added this expression:

```
=runningValue( sum(Fields!one.Value) / sum(Fields!two.Value), Sum, "table1_grp")
```

(`table1_grp` is in internal group).

I copied the value from the `runningValue` textbox in the ratio column in the total row.

**The expression is:**

```
=ReportItems!Textbox55.Value
```

So, the running sum is invisible in the table, but I use the final value in the total row.

---

UPDATE:

My colleague came up with an elegant solution.

In ratio total box, use the following expression:

```
=sum( sum(Fields!one.Value, "table1_grp") / sum(Fields!two.Value, "table1_grp") )
```

adding the scope to the inner sums does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try Sum((Fields!one.Value / Fields!two.Value)).

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work - it gave me the sum of the ratios for all of the underlying data (without summing the fields first). This resulted in an answer of 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a calculated field in your data set that creates the ratio.

**I** - Insert the data field instead of the expression directly in the field.

Now you have it total by right-clicking and selecting add a total.

**II** - Right-click on your data set, select Add calculated field, name it ratio, add your expression here.

Then ratio will be a selection you can add to your table as an **actual field** instead of an expression. You can then total it.